# Invalid write of size 4 trying to implement a stack

Tags: arrays, c, data-structures, stack

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int stack[100];

    stack_push(stack[100], 100, 1);

    print_stack(stack[100], 100);
}

void stack_push(int array[], int size, int data){
    int top = -1;
    if (top>=size){
        printf("Stack is full.");
    } else {
        top++;
        array[top]=data;
    }  
}

int print_stack(int array[], int size){
    if (size == 0){
        return 0;
    } else{
        int i=0;
        while (i<size){
            printf("%d", array[i]);
            i++;
        }      
    }
}
```

When I ran a debugger for my code, it stopped at line 16 with the error "Invalid write of size 4".
I don't know what that means can someone please help me out? I am new to stack overflow.

I expected the array to take input in the form of :
array[top] = data
However, according to vs code, it results in some conflicting data types for stack_push().

Comment: the image is showing up as enter image description

Comment: Don't post code as an image. Please fix.

Comment: ALWAYS enable your compiler's warnings. (For example, you could use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Werror` with gcc.) It would have found your error.

Answer (score 1):

the parameters in an array, size, ...

```
int print_stack(int array[], int size);
void stack_push(int array[], int size, int data);
```

but when you call those functions, you are used an element stack[100]. It seems that you are push the value  of the element of the array stack with the index 100. it is totally wrong. Moreover, you define `int stack[100];` it mean that you are defining an array stack with 100 elements, each element are an integer. the maximum element of the array stack is 100, and the index of the last element is 99 (stack[99])

```
stack_push(stack[100], 100, 1);

print_stack(stack[100], 100);
```

You can fix it by:

```
stack_push(stack, 100, 1);

print_stack(stack, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you pass `stack[100]` as an argument to both `stack_push` and `print_stack` you are not passing the stack, but the value at position `100`, which doesn't exists since the final index is 99 and is of type `int` instead of `int *` (the actual array type). Change the call to `stack` and it should work.

Also, your stack isn't pushing properly (I will guess you just wrote the insert function to begin testing), it is just overwriting the top each time you call it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int print_stack(int array[], int size) {
    if (size == 0){
        return 0;
    } else{
        int i=0;
        while (i<size){
            printf("%d", array[i]);
            i++;
        }
    }
}

void stack_push(int array[], int size, int data) {
    int top = -1;
    if (top>=size){
        printf("Stack is full.");
    }    else{
        top++;
        array[top]=data;
    }     
}

int main() { 
    int stack[100];
    stack_push(stack, 100, 1);
    print_stack(stack, 100);
}
```

Comment: @AkariOozara I tried to do it with just stack as you said but I am still getting error.

Comment: @Meg edited to show the final code. Test it and do note that only the first position of the stack will be changed.

Comment: Why post so much code in this answer when the tiny "fix" is almost invisible?

Comment: Your answer does not answer anything

Answer (score 0):

Stack need a pointer(but it is not real pointer) that indicate where stack lie in.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int stack_push(int* array, int* StackPointer , int data);
void print_stack(int* array, int* TopPointer);

int main(){
    int stack[100] = {0};
    int TopPointer = 0;
    int status = 0;
    for(int m = 0; m < 5; m++){
        status = stack_push(stack, &TopPointer , m + 1);
    if(1 == status){
        ;
    }else{
            printf("Stack is full.Operation is not continue, now operation %d times\n", m);
    }
    }
    print_stack(stack, &TopPointer);
}

int stack_push(int* array, int* StackPointer , int data){
    int top = 0;
    if (*StackPointer >= 99){
        printf("Stack is full.\n");
    return 0;
    } else {
        (*StackPointer)++;
        array[*StackPointer]=data;
    return 1;
    }  
}

void print_stack(int* array, int* TopPointer){
    if (*TopPointer == 0){
        printf("Stack is empty\n");
    } else{
        int i = *TopPointer;
    printf("print stack value:\n");
        while (i > 0){
            printf("%d ", array[i]);
            i--;
        }      
    printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Run it will output:

```
print stack value:
5 4 3 2 1
```

In my code, define stack[0] is stack button, stack[1] is the first data that push stack, when stack pointer to stack[99] that indicate stack is full. Because stack TopPointer is needed for `print_stack` and `stack_push`, so I use it as `int*` type that when value of TopPointer changed be suite for both function.

When print stack, according to first in last out, I print value of stack from stack top.